# How to check if rows are missing from one search versus another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with relevant columns being :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PrmsBlotter](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [BBox] [varchar](250) NOT NULL,
    [RunDateStart] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RunType] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [TestDateFrom] [date] NULL, 
    ...
)
```

BBox is the name of the black box. RunType can be Live or Backtesting. Each live run gets a backtest such that the TestDateFrom of the backtest is equal to RunDateStart of the Live test.

I need to know if there are any live runs that don'e have a matching backtest. I have so far:

```
SELECT t1.BBox, t1.dd, t2.BBox, t2.dd FROM
(SELECT BBox, CONVERT(date,RunDateStart) as dd FROM  [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE RunType = 'Live') t1
LEFT JOIN
(SELECT BBox, CONVERT(date,TestDateFrom) as dd FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE RunType = 'Backtesting') t2
ON (t1.BBox = t2.BBox AND t1.dd = t2.dd)
```

I'm joining two queries one for lives, one for backtests and joining them on bbox names being equal and live's rundatestart being equal to backtest's testdatefrom. That's where I'm stuck. I don't know how to say where there's no match.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `not exists()` to return `'Live'` tests with no corresponding `'Backtesting'` with matching `BBox` and `TestDateFrom` to `RunDateStart`:

```
select 
    t.BBox
  , convert(date, t.RunDateStart) as dd
from [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter] t
where t.RunType = 'Live'
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter] i
    where i.RunType = 'Backtesting'
      and i.BBox = t.BBox
      and convert(date,i.TestDateFrom) = convert(date,t.RunDateStart)
  )
```

Comment: what does select 1 mean?

Comment: `select 1` doesn't mean anything because `exists()` and `not exists()` do not actually return any columns. It is the same as saying `select *` or `select null` in this context. There is no **runtime** performance difference between `select 1` and `select *` when using `exists()`. Although using `select 1` will avoid having to examine any unneeded metadata for that table during query compilation. 
[EXISTS Subqueries: SELECT 1 vs. SELECT * - Conor Cunningham](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/conor/exists-subqueries-select-1-vs-select/)

Answer (score 0):

You need a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT l.BBox, l.rdday, bt.BBox, bt.btday FROM
FROM (SELECT BBox, CONVERT(date, RunDateStart) as rdday
      FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
      WHERE RunType = 'Live'
     ) l LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT BBox, CONVERT(date, TestDateFrom) as btday
      FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
      WHERE RunType = 'Backtesting'
     ) bt
     ON l.BBox = bt.BBox AND l.rtday = bt.btday
WHERE bt.BBox IS NULL;
```

Note:  `dd` is a bad name for a column, because it is a keyword used for the `datepart()` function.

I think you can also do this with `group by` and `having`:

```
SELECT BBox, CONVERT(date, RunDateStart) as rdday
FROM [PrimusGroup].[dbo].[PrmsBlotter]
WHERE RunType IN ('Live', 'BackTesting')
GROUP BY BBox, CONVERT(date, RunDateStart)
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN RunType = 'Live' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 AND
       SUM(CASE WHEN RunType = 'BackTesting' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 ;
```